# Android error parsing post response org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: php, android, json

I'm writing an Android app that can parse JSON returned from PHP webpages, and I keep getting "org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0" in Logcat. Here's the code:

```
public class HttpConnect {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final String url = "http://foo/bar/handler.php";
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONObject resultJson;
    boolean status;

    public boolean sendJson(String value) {
        try {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonString", URLEncoder.encode(
                value, "utf-8")));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            resultJson = new JSONObject(result);
        }
        if (resultJson.getString("success") == "true")
            status = true;
        else
            status = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
    //...
}
```

Server side:

```
$arr = array('success' => 'true', 'status' => 'RegSuccess', 'userid' => $userid, 'authkey' => $authKey);
$jsonString = json_encode($arr);
echo $jsonString;
```

Postman gets the response, which is correct:

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "status": "RegSuccess",
    "userid": "2",
    "authkey": "OvOWwCjIXoYtbjsIdTVI"
}
```

But the android app pops error:

> 08-07 16:44:34.044: W/System.err(13880): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:155)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:172)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at com.lafickens.rescued.HttpConnect.sendJson(HttpConnect.java:49)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at com.lafickens.rescued.LoginActivity$UserRegisterTask.sendCredentials(LoginActivity.java:369)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at com.lafickens.rescued.LoginActivity$UserRegisterTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:325)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at com.lafickens.rescued.LoginActivity$UserRegisterTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
>   08-07 16:44:34.049: W/System.err(13880):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   08-07 16:44:34.054: W/System.err(13880):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   08-07 16:44:34.054: W/System.err(13880):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   08-07 16:44:34.054: W/System.err(13880):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   08-07 16:44:34.054: W/System.err(13880):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   08-07 16:44:34.054: W/System.err(13880):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Debugging shows string `result` is empty, and `contentLength` of `httpResponse` is 0. The same java code works perfectly fine for another web service, but not for mine. Puzzling :s

Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is use [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) for your networking operations . It is for faster and better networking.

It nicely plays with all kinds of Json requests and also String request.

Comment: Yep it works. Thank you so much! But the question remains: why can't 'httpPost' and 'httpResponse' get response the way Volley does?... Any clue?